# Find all the closest positive integer solutions within a bound for a simple linear equation

Tags: equation-solving, mathematical-optimization, linear-algebra, finance, inequalities

Suppose I have a linear equation/inequality like

$$xA+yB \leq C,$$

with $x,y \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}_{\neq 0}$ and $A,B,C \in \{x | x = 0.01\mu, \forall \mu \in \mathbb{Z}^+_{\neq0}\}$. I want to find all the closest (positive integer) pairs $(x,y)$ such that:

$$\delta \leq xA+yB \leq C, \delta\in\mathbb{R}.$$

How can this be done in Mathematica? I want to find the closest positive integer solution to the line. I can do this visually, and just circle pairs, but it would be nice to have an automatic method to generate such pairs.

---

As $x,y$ are clearly "quantities" of things, and $A,B,C$ are "monetary values" an example of a linear equation (with a $\delta = 76.92$) might be something like this:

$$76.92 \leq 4.54x + 7.31y \leq 81.92$$

It would be nice if this could be generalized for more variables too, that is, like this:

$$\delta \leq x_0A_0+x_1A_1+\dots +x_nA_n \leq C, \delta \in \mathbb{R}$$

With $x_i\in \mathbb{Z}^+_{\neq 0}$ and $A_i\in \{x | x = 0.01\mu, \forall \mu \in \mathbb{Z}^+_{\neq0}\}$ as before.

Comment: Won't there, in general, be an infinite number of solutions?

Comment: Positive integer solutions bounded by the line and the chosen $\delta$. It's basically all the positive integer solutions within a very thin trapezoid.

Comment: Very thin, *infinitely long*, trapezoid.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork, no, why do you think it's infinitely long? I don't understand. Maybe I'm not being clear enough.

Comment: Please draw a figure in the $x-y$ plane illustrating your problem and the solution region.  Also note that @AnxonPués answer gives $5$ solutions, but if you change his last value to $10$ you'll get 10 solutions, or 50, or 1000....

Comment: @DavidG.Stork, https://imgur.com/a/HAuMA

Comment: Huh???  So what numbers *are* you dealing with?

Comment: You must be trolling me. $x,y,A,B,C \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}_{\neq 0}$, _i.e._, positive non-zero...

Comment: I'm a sophisticated mathematician (former professor of math), with a MSE reputation nearly 20,000, who sees this is a very poorly defined question, and that it took four comments/postings for you to recognize what should have been obvious from the beginning.  Even with your belated restriction to positive, non-zero you *still* do not see that there are an infinite number of solutions.  (Over and out.)

Comment: Ok, I will concede that, $\sqrt{x^2+y^2} \rightarrow \infty$ as $x$ or $y \rightarrow \infty$, but I'm not dealing with such numbers.

Comment: Are 'A,B,C' to be regarded as fixed positive integer values? A concrete example would be really helpful here.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau, see my edit. $A,B,C$ are actually in a really specific set.

Comment: Have you seen both `FrobeniusSolve[]` and `KnapsackSolve[]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is a generalisation of a [previous](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/167066/find-optimal-integer-solution-to-linear-equation-wolfram-alpha/167088) question.

Non-negative solutions to this linear Diophantine equation for positive coefficients {a,b} are given by `NonnegLinearDiophantineTwo[{a,b},c]`.

```
NonnegLinearDiophantineTwo[{a_Integer, b_Integer}, c_Integer] :=
   Block[{g, r, s, k},
      {g, {r, s}} = ExtendedGCD[a, b];
      Transpose[{r*c + b*k, s*c - a*k}/g /. k->Range[Ceiling[-r*c/b],Floor[s*c/a]]]
   ]
```

Make a table of solutions for the range of allowed c, then pick those with positive solutions.

```
Pick[#, Map[FreeQ[#, 0] &, #]] &[
   Select[
      Table[{c, NonnegLinearDiophantineTwo[{454, 731}, c]}, {c, 7692, 8192}],
      #[[2]] =!= {} &]
]
```

> {{7741, {{9, 5}}}, {7764, {{1, 10}}}, {7818, {{14, 2}}}, {7841, {{6, 
>       7}}}, {7918, {{11, 4}}}, {7941, {{3, 9}}}, {7995, {{16, 
>       1}}}, {8018, {{8, 6}}}, {8095, {{13, 3}}}, {8118, {{5, 8}}}}

As @J.M. points out, the built-in function `FrobeniusSolve[{a,b},c]` is designed to solve these types of equations. `FrobeniusSolve` generalises to any number of coefficients. However, `FrobeniusSolve` is much slower than `NonnegLinearDiophantineTwo` in the case of two coefficients.

```
Pick[#, Map[FreeQ[#, 0] &, #]] &[
   Select[
      Table[{c, FrobeniusSolve[{454, 731}, c]}, {c, 7692, 8192}],
      #[[2]] =!= {} &]
]
```

Answer (score 1):

if you have actual values of a,b,c,d this works

```
FindInstance[1 < 5 x + 2 y  < 8, {x, y}, Integers, 5]
```

{{x -> 110, y -> -272}, {x -> 186, y -> -462}, {x -> 980, 
  y -> -2449}, {x -> 536, y -> -1339}, {x -> 650, y -> -1623

to have a graph intuition about possible solutions I tried this, it's easy to choose between three cases, no solutions, a few solutions or infinite.

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[{y = c/b - c/a x, y = d/b - c/a x}, {x, -30, 30}], {a, -8, 
  8}, {b, -8, 8}, {c, -8, 8}, {d, -24, 24}]
```

It will be good if someone, can open ligth about this discusion options face to the values of a, b, c, d.

Comment: This shows there is an infinite number of solutions.

Comment: I'm looking for positive integer solutions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Solve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve) or [`Reduce`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reduce) to enumerate all of the possibilities:

```
(* example *)
a = 11;
b = 4;
c = 30;
δ = 20;

Solve[x>0 && y>0 && δ < x a + b y < c, {x, y}, Integers]
```

> {{x -> 1, y -> 3}, {x -> 1, y -> 4}, {x -> 2, y -> 1}}

If you just want to find the closest point, you can use [`LinearProgramming`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LinearProgramming):

```
LinearProgramming[
    -{a, b},
    {{a, b}},
    {{c-1/2, -1}},
    1,
    Integers    
]
```

> LinearProgramming::lpip: Warning: integer linear programming will use a machine-precision approximation of the inputs.
>
> {1, 4}

or [`Maximize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Maximize):

```
Maximize[{x a + b y, δ < x a + b y < c && x>0 && y>0}, {x, y}, Integers]
```

> {27, {x -> 1, y -> 4}}

Comment: Can't find my key to my student Mathematica disk. Is there a way to run these functions remotely on a Mathematica server?

Comment: @twoblacklinesinthemiddle You could sign up for a free trial of [Mathematica Online](https://www.wolframcloud.com/).

Answer (score 1):

A comment (with figure):

A large number of solutions:

[image]

Comment: You are forgetting that the constraint is $x,y,a,b,C>0$. If $x,y,a,b,C>0$, then you cannot have a "negative slope" as your graphic depicts.

Comment: Now that you have changed your graphic, yes, there are a "large number of solutions," but not infinite. https://imgur.com/a/HAuMA

Comment: @ David G. Stork, I would like to know how you made this grpah, and also how you made graphs in answer. Same about to put the equations over the lines

Comment: *Mathematica*.  (I deleted the code yesterday, but if you learn how to program in *Mathematica* such figures are quite simple.)

Answer (score 1):

Using the `Region` concept it is more explicit to arrive to solutions, if any.

```
RegionPlot[
 ImplicitRegion[{-11 > -5  x - 7 y > -31 && x > 0 && y > 0  }, {x, 
   y}], AspectRatio -> {1, 1}, GridLines -> {Range[5], Range[3]}]
```

[image]

```
Solve[{x, y} \[Element] 
  ImplicitRegion[{-11 > -5  x - 7 y > -31 && x > 0 && y > 0  }, {x, 
    y}], {x, y}, Integers]

{{x -> 1, y -> 1}, {x -> 1, y -> 2}, {x -> 1, y -> 3}, {x -> 2, 
  y -> 1}, {x -> 2, y -> 2}, {x -> 3, y -> 1}, {x -> 3, 
  y -> 2}, {x -> 4, y -> 1}}
```